# Angular 2.0 - How to get query params

Tags: angular

Supposing I have this following URL - http://localhost:4200?runID=5555

How can I pass query param "runID" to my app.component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent {}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get `queryParams` using the current `ActivatedRoute`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit():void{
         this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
             console.log(params);
         //params is an object here, it should be {runID:5555}
         });
    }
}
```

`route.queryParams` is an `Observable<any>` that will emit each time the query params are changed and thus will emit once the dom is initialized (that's why I subscribe in the `ngOnInit()` method).

More informations on `route.queryParams` in [anguar.io docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/ActivatedRoute-interface.html#!#queryParams-anchor).